# How to implement UISearchController in UITableView - Swift

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I am a newbie to Swift and I am trying to add search functionality to my `UITableView` which is in a `UIViewController` class. I googled a lot and found that `UISearchDisplayController` has been deprecated and replaced by UISearchController. When I tried to search for tutorials I did not find any specifically for `UITableView`. Some of them were for implementing in `UITableViewController`. So here are my questions:

1. Can we implement `UISearchController` in a `UITableView` that is in a `UIViewController` class? (I guess we can)
2. If we can, please convert these line of codes written in Objective-C. Or if there are some really good tutorials please let me know.

   ```
   @property (strong, nonatomic) UISearchController *searchController;

   UITableViewController *searchResultsController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];

   // Init UISearchController with the search results controller
    self.searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:searchResultsController];

   // Link the search controller
   self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
   ```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417591/uisearchcontroller-in-a-uiviewcontroller)

**EDIT :**
I am trying to assign the search results updater in as

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    override func viewDidLoad() {

       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor() 
       self.addTableViewWithSection() 
       self.searchResultsController = UITableViewController()           
       var controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)            
       controller.searchResultsUpdater = self           
       controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false   
    }
}
```

*However on the line  controller.searchResultsUpdater = self i get the eroor as Cannot assign a value of typ "ViewController" to a value of type "**UISearchResultsUpdating**?" *.. So i really doubt if i can use **UISearchController** in **UIViewController** type class.*

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, the way search works has been radically changed for what I consider to be a better system. The new system is much better and straight to the point for most simple implementations. Using it is pretty straightforward.

First, make your class comply with the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol.

`class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {}`

Add it the search controller property:

```
class MyTableViewController: UTableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
}
```

Add the search bar in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
}
```

And finally, implement the `updateSearchResults:for` method that comes from the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

}
```

Your implementation of this method will of course depend on where you are searching the data from. It will update your current table view with the contents of your search as you type them. Make sure you update your data source and reload the table view in the `updateSearchResultsForSearchController` method. Again, it updates as you type so make sure that if your data to search in is big or if you are searching from the internet, add some concurrency in this method.

If you want to use a different controller to populate your search results with, you can pass that VC when initialising the `searchController` property.

**EDIT**: I have reread your question and it looks like I forgot to add something important.

UITableViewController has a member called `tableView`. You can grab the controller's table view , but to populate your `UITableView`, you don't need to touch it. You can't use the SearchController logic ***directly*** with UITableView. You gotta work with the controller to get it there. Use the UITableViewController delegate and data source methods to get your table UI updated with your search results.

Please read on using UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, and UITableViewDataSource so you can understand how to get your search results there.

Comment: what if this line was
 class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {} as class MYTableView: UIViewController and had tableview created or have an outlet there ...does this work?

Comment: The name of class doesn't matter but it makes no sense to leave the Controller part out as you are effectively defining a controller, not a view. Also you don't need to manually create a UITableView because UITableViewController has one ready to be used by you. Whether you created this controller in IB or fully by code, your controller can reference it via `self.tableView`. But again, you don't need to do that to populate your table view.

Comment: The scope of this answer doesn't deal with using the table view controller, the delegate, or the data source. But feel free to read a [tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-to-the-ios-uitableviewcontroller) on the topic.

Comment: i had already a ViewController with many sub views and a large TableView and i have to implement search functionality to that table view..so ,i am seeking around ...anyway thanks man!!! i will try to implement this

Comment: can you please see the updated question..i am really stuck now

Comment: I LOL'd when I got to: "add some concurrency" :)

Comment: If you want to add to any UIView then you can use 
`myView. addSubview(searchController.searchBar)`

Answer (score 27):

In case of anyone, who is freaking around like me..this code might help

```
class ViewController: UIViewController , UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,UISearchResultsUpdating {

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    var tabledata = ["lucques","chickendijon","godaddy","amazon","chris","ambata","bankofamerica","abelcine","AUTO + TRANSPORTATION","BILLS + UTILITIES","FOOD + DINING","HEALTH","AutoCare", "Auto Payment" , "Gas+Fuel","Electric Bill", "Internet/Television","Fast Foodd", "Gorceries" , "Restaurants","Gym Membership", "Health Insurance","auto","note-bullet","knife","heart"]

    var filteredTableData = [String]()
    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tblView.delegate = self
        tblView.dataSource = self
        self.resultSearchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            controller.searchBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Black
            controller.searchBar.barTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            controller.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
            self.tblView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar
            return controller
        })()
        self.tblView.reloadData()
    }

     func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if self.resultSearchController.active {
           return self.filteredTableData.count
        }else{
            return self.tabledata.count
       }
    }
     func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var section = indexPath.section
        var row = indexPath.row
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"addCategoryCell")
        cell.selectionStyle =  UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)

        if self.resultSearchController.active {
              cell.textLabel?.text = filteredTableData[indexPath.row]
        } else {
                 cell.textLabel?.text = tabledata[indexPath.row]
        }
        return cell
    }

    func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
        filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
        let array = (tabledata as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
        filteredTableData = array as! [String]
        self.tblView.reloadData()

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you're assumption that you can scope initialize a variable is a very very bad assumption. Never, ever do what you're doing with self.resultSearchController in a method body.

Comment: should i make that lazy variable and intialize?

Comment: Yes, very much so if you would like the initialization all in one place

Comment: yeah..that might be good..this was the one when i was learning about SearchController

Comment: What if , that i want to get the indexpath of search results , and have a segue , how to read the indexpath for search results ? Thanks you

Comment: after you search..you can go with didselectrowatindexpath delegate method of tableview and segue from there

Answer (score 0):

For those looking for a bit more context on all the aspects of implementing this, here's a [tutorial on how to implement UISearchController](https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial)

In addition to [the above answer by Andy Ibanez](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664483/35516), you also need to add code to your UITableViewDataSource methods to show the newly filtered results in the tableview.

Also, don't forget to call `tableView.reloadData()` in your updateSearchResults method - the UISearchController does not automatically tell the tableView to reload its data.