# Implementing a Search Bar in a Table View

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm currently learning iOS development. Unfortunately the course I've signed up for is based on iOS 7 and doesn't seem to have any support. I have Xcode 7 however and have become very stuck on trying to implement a search bar in a table view. I've been searching for answers on how to fix the 'searchDisplayController' deprecation, and while there is information out there, being new to Objective-C, I haven't worked out how to fix my issue.

I have a very basic TableView app that simply displays the months of the year in a TableView. I've added the "Search Bar and Search Display Controller" to the TableView. Here is the first part of my code where Xcode tells me that 'searchDisplayController' is deprecated within 'TableViewController.m':

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {
        return [_filteredResults count];
    }
    else {
       return [_monthsOfTheYear count];
    }
}
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could let me know what I need to do instead or to point me to a tutorial that could help me to understand it.

Thank you!

Comment: If people take the time to read your question, it's a good idea to post feedback.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `UISearchController`. You may go through [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISearchController/index.html) for this. Here is one [good tutorial](http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/) on this. You may also look into this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664315/how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-in-uitableview-swift). And [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPJYIOtez7I) would also add into your knowledge base.

Comment: I've had a look through all these tutorials and links you posted but I still can't get my head around it. I also need to program this using Objective-C so the Swift video didn't help unfortunately. Do I need to add the "UISearchController" to my header file, i.e. in my code, I currently have: "@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController" - so do I need to add UISearchController in here?

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchController` replaces `UISearchDisplayController`. [Here is a tutorial](http://www.jhof.me/simple-uisearchcontroller-implementation/) re: how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

add this Property

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

and add this code in your viewDidLoad

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
definesPresentationContext = true
yourTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
yourTableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: searchController.searchBar.frame.height)
```

for more detail check this [tutorial](http://http:/https://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) for swift and [this tutorial](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/add-search-table-view-tutorial-ios8-swift)