# Hide view when user scrolls down in tableview

Tags: ios, swift

I have a filterbar, which is a UIView as well as a tableView in my controller like so:

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    sortSalonsByDistanceAndReload()
}    

func setupViews() {
    view.addSubview(filterBar)
    view.addSubview(tableView)

    filterBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    filterBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    filterBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true

    filterBarHeightLC = filterBar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
    filterBarHeightLC?.isActive = true

    tableView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: filterBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

}
```

I want to make the filterBar dissapear when the user scrolls down on the tableView, and then reappear when the user scrolls up

Answer (score 0):

You can use Search Controller. Take a look at [How to implement UISearchController in UITableView - SWIFT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664315/how-to-implement-uisearchcontroller-in-uitableview-swift)

if it doesn't work out for you , you could add as a section or part of header view

Answer (score 0):

The `delegate` of your `tableView` should implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` method `scrollViewDidScroll:` and query the `contentOffset.y` property on the `scrollView` (your tableView). Then it depends on when you want the bar to appear: only on the top, or also whenever the user scroll up inside the tableView. You could sync the `contentOffset.y` difference with the `filterBar`s top constraint's constant (ranging from -44 to 0). It might be better to inset your tableView and update that inset as well (from 0 to 44).
If your filterBar could be implemented with a navigation bar from a `UINavigationController` you might just do `navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true`, but I don't know your view controller setup.